# how can i decode this transactions and see what it contain?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, metamask, ethers.js, cpp-ethereum

I'm interested in decoding the information within this transaction, which can be found at the following link:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1013929251687ff7f6a7e2e0c7e3caae6fd93a2342dd5ad9793ff33c5802269f

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's an image.

Under the input data field, you can select a format. Select utf-8 and you will see the data.

[image]

Comment: How can i decode this txs using code, if it's an image, i should write buffer to create a jpg

Comment: Not sure how to convert the data to an image. This is outside the scope of Ethereum. To decode the transaction you want to look into the logs of the transaction receipt and get the bytecode from there.